# Add \n to __repr__

Tags: python

I am trying to format the `__repr__` of an object so that it separates each element of an array by a new line character.

This is the class:

```
class Data:
    taskArray = []
    def __init__(self,units):
        self.units = units
    def __repr__(self):
        return str("Units: {0} \n{1}".format(self.units, self.taskArray))
```

At the moment it will print like this:

```
Units: 4
[Element1, Element2, Element3]
```

I would like it to print like this:

```
Units: 4
[Element1,
Element2,
Element3]
```

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: You need to convert your list to a string to print it. Check if my answer below makes sense to you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
>>> class Data:
...     taskArray = ["foo", "bar"]
...     def __init__(self,units):
...         self.units = units
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return "Units: {0} \n[{1}]".format(self.units, ",\n".join(repr(t) for t in self.taskArray))
... 
>>> print(Data(4))
Units: 4 
[foo,
bar]
```

Comment: Lists usually print their elements with `repr(t)` instead of `str(t)`. You don't have to do it that way, and in many cases it won't make a difference.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, `join` need strings to work so I used `str` (which in many cases call to `repr`), I think is easier to understand but I see you point and you are right.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a string with each element terminated with `,\n` out of your taskArray list to achieve it. You can join elements of a list in a string using [str.join()](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)

```
class Data:

    def __init__(self,units, taskArray):
        self.units = units
        self.taskArray = taskArray
    def __repr__(self):
        taskArrayStr = ',\n'.join([str(task) for task in self.taskArray])
        return str("Units: {0} \n[{1}]".format(self.units, taskArrayStr))

d = Data(4, ['Element1', 'Element2', 'Element3'])
print(d)
d = Data(4, [1, 'Element2', 3.0])
print(d)
```

Your output then will be

```
d = Data(4, ['Element1', 'Element2', 'Element3'])
print(d)
#Units: 4 
#[Element1,
#Element2,
#Element3]
d = Data(3, [1, 'Element2', 3.0])
print(d)
#Units: 3 
#[1,
#Element2,
#3.0]
```

Comment: This will fail if any of the list elements aren't strings

Comment: I missed it, updated my code to cover it. Thanks for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is:

```
class Data:
    taskArray = ['foo', 'bar']
    def __init__(self,units):
        self.units = units
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Units: {0} \n[{1}]".format(self.units, ',\n'.join(map(str, self.taskArray)))
print(Data(4))
```

Output:

```
Units: 4 
[foo,
bar]
```

Comment: repr is a better choice if you want to be consistent with how list itself does it

Answer (score 0):

By far the easiest way to do this is to use the `pprint` module. You should use that to pretty print arbitrary objects unless you require a specific output format that it doesn't support.